# .rdlc showing second page with header

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, report, rdlc

My application developed with using VS12 and using .rdlc and rendering as pdf format. My problem is .rdlc file rendering second page blank with the header. My requirement is rdlc file has to render to the second page only if the body has more date to display if not then it has to fit first page only but in my case, data is fitted to the first page but and in second page it is displaying with the header.

I tried with ConsumeContainerWhitespace=true, but this not solved my problem.

I even tried by adjusting margins as per below link
https://forums.asp.net/t/1752865.aspx
Below are the measurements.
.rdlc file size - width 8.5in X Height 11in and margins (Left - 0.5in    Right 0.25in    Top 0.5in    Bottom 0.25in)

.rdlc body size width 7.4in X Height 4.51128in

Can anyone help on this?

Thanks in advance!